# Using variables for a partial template

Tags: handlebars.js, partials

I'm definitely missing something about the way Handlebars works. I need to call different partials depending on the value of a variable. Currently the only way I've found to do it is this:

```
<template name="base">
  {{#if a}}{{> a}}{{/if}}
  {{#if b}}{{> b}}{{/if}}
  {{#if c}}{{> c}}{{/if}}
</template>
```

And in the corresponding JS:

```
Template.base.a = function () {
  return (mode === "a");
}

Template.base.b = function () {
  return (mode === "b");
}

Template.base.c = function () {
  return (mode === "c");
}
```

...which strikes me as extremely verbose. What I'd *really* like to do is something like:

```
<template name="base">
  {{> {{mode}} }}
</template>
```

In other words, the value of `mode` would be the name of the partial that is called.

This seems like it must be a very common use-case, but I can't find any examples of this online. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The official **dynamic partials** (from Joshua) really should be the default answer here.

Answer (score 18):

The partials are stored in `Handlebars.partials` so you can access them by hand in your own helper. There are a few tricky bits here though:

1. The contents of `Handlebars.partials` can be strings or functions so you have to compile the partials on first use.
2. Handlebars doesn't know if the partial will be `text/plain` or `text/html` so you'll need to call your helper in `{{{...}}}` or `{{...}}` as appropriate.
3. This stuff isn't exactly documented (at least not anywhere that I can find) so you have to reverse engineer the Handlebars source and fumble about with `console.log(arguments)` to figure out how to use `Handlebars.partials`.
4. You have to pass `this` by hand when you call the helper.

Fear not, it isn't really that complicated. Something simple like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('partial', function(name, ctx, hash) {
    var ps = Handlebars.partials;
    if(typeof ps[name] !== 'function')
        ps[name] = Handlebars.compile(ps[name]);
    return ps[name](ctx, hash);
});
```

should do the trick. Then you can say:

```
{{{partial mode this}}}
```

and get on with more interesting things.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/YwNJ3/2/

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Like you say the official docs are REALLY bad when it comes to partials.

Comment: @Fractalf: I hear you, the official "docs" leave much to be desired, I've had to go through the source code more than once to figure what's going on.

Comment: if you need server-side version, you can find it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27820812/1563880

Answer (score 14):

**Update for 2016**: [Version 3 of handlebars added](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/release-notes.md) [**Dynamic Partials**](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html). From the docs:

It's possible to dynamically select the partial to be executed by using sub expression syntax.

```
{{> (whichPartial) }}
```

Will evaluate `whichPartial` and then render the partial whose name is returned by this function.

Subexpressions do not resolve variables, so `whichPartial` must be a function. If a simple variable has the partial name, it's possible to resolve it via the `lookup` helper.

```
 {{> (lookup . 'myVariable') }}
```