# Express Handlebars 'partial' helper

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js

I want to implement something like this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18431716/1563880
with [this lib](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars)

Here is my code:

```
var expressHandlebars  = require('express-handlebars');
var Handlebars = expressHandlebars.create({
    ....
    helpers: {
        partial: function(partialName, context, hash) {
            return Handlebars.getPartials()
                 .then(function(partials){
                     return partials[partialName](context, hash);
                 });
        }
    }
})
```

and use it in this way:

`{{{partial partialName this}}} <!-- partialName is a variable -->`

but result is 
`[object Object]`
and this object is Promise instance.

How can I get template content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final code should be like this:

```
var expressHandlebars  = require('express-handlebars');
var Handlebars = expressHandlebars.create({
    ....
    helpers: {
        partial: function(partialName, context, hash) {
            return Handlebars.partials[partialName](context, hash); //changes
        }
    },
    ....
});

Handlebars.getPartials()
    .then(function(partials){
        Handlebars.partials = partials;
    });
```

Please, correct me if I wrong